# Scrapy splash can't find element

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-splash, splash-js-render

**Problem:**

I am using scrapy splash to scrape a web page. However it seems the css path for `imageURL` does not return any element but the ones for `name` and `category` worked fine. (xpath and selector are all copied directly from Chrome.)

**Things I've Tried:**

At first I thought it's because the page has not been fully loaded when `parse` gets called so I changed the `wait` argument for SplashRequest to 5 but it did not help. I also downloaded a copy of the html response from splash GUI (http://localhost:8050) and verified that the xpath/selectors all work well on the downloaded copy. Here I assumed that this html would be exactly what scrapy sees in `parse` so I couldn't make sense of why it wouldn't work inside scrapy script.

**Code:**

Here is my code:

```
class NikeSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'nike'
allowed_domains = ['nike.com', 'store.nike.com']
start_urls = ['https://www.nike.com/t/air-vapormax-flyknit-utility-running-shoe-XPTbVZzp/AH6834-400']

def start_requests(self):
    for url in self.start_urls:
        yield SplashRequest (
            url=url,
            callback=self.parse,
            args= {
                'wait': 5
            }
        )

def parse(self, response):

    name = response.xpath('//*[@id="RightRail"]/div/div[1]/div[1]/h1/text()').extract_first()
    imageURL = response.css('#PDP > div > div:nth-child(2) > div.css-1jldkv2 > div:nth-child(1) > div > div > div.d-lg-h.bg-white.react-carousel > div > div.slider-container.horizontal.react-carousel-slides > ul > li.slide.selected > div > picture:nth-child(3) > img::attr(src)').extract_first()
    category = response.css('#RightRail > div > div.d-lg-ib.mb0-sm.mb8-lg.u-full-width > div.ncss-base.pr12-sm > h2::text').extract_first()
    url = response.url


    if name != None and imageURL != None and category != None:
        item = ProductItem()
        item['name'] = name
        item['imageURL'] = imageURL
        item['category'] = category
        item['URL'] = url

        yield item
```

Answer (score 0):

May they use different formatting but for me it's (`source::attr(srcset)` at the end):

```
imageURL = response.css('#PDP > div > div:nth-child(2) > div.css-1jldkv2 > div:nth-child(1) > div > div > div.d-lg-h.bg-white.react-carousel > div > div.slider-container.horizontal.react-carousel-slides > ul > li.slide.selected > div > picture:nth-child(3) > source::attr(srcset)').extract_first()
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! I think css selector is not the problem here - my selector does get the img element I needed when I test in browser. Did I miss anything?

Comment: I have tested in browser and in Scrapy

Comment: Why mine won’t work in Scrapy? It works in browser too.

Comment: The only reason I can see it's some kind of RANDOM HTML formatting

Comment: Sometimes it's `img` but sometimes `source` etc

Comment: Try to save HTML from Scrapy (I mean Splash response HTML) and check

Comment: You mean the response object in parse function?

Comment: It seems the problem is scrapy parser added some </source> tags automatically, which caused the selector to fail. (i.e. can't find the img element). <source> tags are not closed on the original website. Here is what running `#PDP > div > div:nth-child(2) > div.css-1jldkv2 > div:nth-child(1) > div > div > div.d-lg-h.bg-white.react-carousel > div > div.slider-container.horizontal.react-carousel-slides > ul > li.slide.selected > div > picture:nth-child(3)` gives me and you can clearly see there IS an img tag.

Comment: <picture><source srcset="https://c.static-nike.com/a/images/t_PDP_1280_v1/f_auto/ozbek7lpzqbi5duregk1/air-vapormax-flyknit-utility-running-shoe-XPTbVZzp.jpg" media="(max-width: 639px)"><source srcset="omitted" media="(min-width: 640px) and (max-width: 1023px)"><source srcset="omitted" media="(min-width: 1024px)"><img class="css-10f9kvm u-full-width u-full-height css-3p6im7" src="omitted" alt="omitted"></source></source></source></picture>

Comment: I believe it's a bug in splash parser. </source> tags are added at incorrect locations, which cause selectors to fail. @gangabass

Comment: My original selector works after removing the `>` before img. Incorrect </source> tags are failing this child combinator selector.